# why does this return a unexpected value?

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Something
{
public:
    int data;


    Something(int data)
    {
        data = data; //
    }
};

int main()
{   
    Something s = Something(4);
    cout << s.data << endl; 
    return 0;

}
```

When I run the above code, I got output 32764. I know it can be fixed by changing data = data by
(*this).data = data or this->data = data. I was just thought the above code would work out also.

Comment: `data = data;` sets the local variable `data` to the value the local variable `data` has. Not so useful but allowed. It does not modify the class member with the same name because it is shadowed. I would make the names different (not necessary but less confusing) and use the constructors initializer list. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/)

Comment: `Something(int data)
    {
        data = data; 
    }` wants to become `Something(int data) : data(data) 
    { }`

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer initialization over assignment:

```
Something(int data) : data(data) {}
```

In your code `data` is the local variable, the parameter passed to the constructor. You are assigning the value of `data` to `data` which effectively does nothing.

Here `: data(data)` is special syntax for the constructors initializer list. `data(...)` is the class member, while `...(data)` is the parameter. Note that this is a special case where you can refer to two different variables via the exact same name. You can still use a different name for the parameter, what you choose is only based on opinions, personal perference and possibly coding standards you have to adhere to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Something(int data)
{
    data = data; //
}
```

I consider this a really bad way to code this. You've defined a method that overrides a class-level variable, which is a really bad idea. To fix this, you can do one of two things:

```
Something(int _data)
{
    data = _data; //
}

Something(int data)
{
    this->data = data; //
}
```

I do the first one. I think it's evil to hide class variables, but you'll find a lot of code that does the second, at least in constructors. A lot of IDEs will flag this as a warning.

Comment: `Something(int data) : data(data) {}` is the *preferred* way to handle this, without having to rename anything. Then there is no ambiguity at all over which `data` refers to the class member and which `data` refers to the constructor parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, you're right. 3 ways to fix this. Personally, I still don't like it and would still pass it as _data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even with the member initializer list it is still reasonable to use different names to avoid confusion in the body or other initializers. I agree though, that using the initializer list should be preferred.

Comment: @walnut you can use similar argument for the opposite, more names means more chance for confusion. in `Something(int data) : data(data) {}` there is no way to confuse the two

Comment: My personal take is simple: don't overload variable names. Ever. You might get away with it, but it's also a great way to have errors that you just can't figure out.